# reset a countdown column to initial value in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, countdown

I'm running pgAdmin v5.2 over postgres v13.3

So I hit a wall with this one...
I'm running a query on a flight log table which is constantly updated with new flights data.
In it there is `engn_hrs_contdwn` column which calculates via  window SUM function the accumulated hrs based on each individual flight time (`hobs_total`) which are then being deducted from 1200 which is a given value upon reaching an engine **MUST** be replaced.
This is the query that I run:

```
SELECT      fleet.fleet_id,
            (flt_log.date || ' '|| flt_log.tkof_01_time)::timestamp  AS date,
            flt_log.hobs_total,
            1200-SUM (hobs_total)OVER (PARTITION BY fleet_id ORDER BY (flt_log.date || ' '|| flt_log.tkof_01_time)::timestamp
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                 AND CURRENT ROW) AS engn_hrs_contdwn
            
 FROM flt_log,fleet
 WHERE flt_log.aircraft_id = fleet.fleet_id 
 AND fleet_id = 2
;
```

| fleet_id | date | hobs_total | engn_hrs_contdwn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-08-09 08:49:00 | 0.20 | 1199.80 |
| 2 | 2020-08-09 11:17:00 | 3.70 | 1196.10 |
| 2 | 2020-08-09 15:42:00 | 0.70 | 1195.40 |
| 2 | 2020-08-09 17:54:00 | 2.40 | 1193.00 |
| 2 | 2020-08-12 07:21:00 | 0.50 | 1192.50 |
| 2 | 2020-08-13 06:50:00 | 2.40 | 1190.10 |
| 2 | 2020-08-13 15:11:00 | 1.50 | 1188.60 |
| 2 | 2020-08-13 20:35:00 | 0.70 | 1187.90 |
| 2 | 2020-08-14 09:17:00 | 2.40 | 1185.50 |

This query works OK on calculating the remaining hrs but when reaching 0 it then returns  negative values which are of course useless for calculating the countdown for a new engine.

My problem is how to reset the countdown initial value back to 1200 every time the `engn_hrs_contdwn` hit below 0 - so that the `engn_hrs_contdwn` column will start the countdown for the new engine and so on and so on.

Being novice at postgresql (and programming in general...) I researched this issue over the web and came across RECURSIVE QUERY and CASE FUNCTION which I think maybe the direction I should take for tackling this issue.
But quite honestly I got completely lost going over tutorials on these subjects and failed so far in my efforts.
Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: . . You can put text tables in to the question.  One simple way to format the data uses triple backticks before and after the data table.

Comment: Why are you storing date and time values in a `text` column? That is really bad idea

Comment: I'm not. it's a timestamp data type column. 
Maybe it translates as text here but on  pgAdmin it is a timestamp datatype for sure

Comment: Maybe the very idea of resetting `engn_hrs_contdwn` needs attention. I think  that having an `engines` table where each engine has `engn_hrs_contdwn`, `vehicle_id` and a status of either `in_service` or `retired` will be more adequate. So  `engn_hrs_contdwn` is not reset at reaching end of life but instead the engine is retired and a new one is inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, I should have mentioned that the hobs counter is not connected directly to the engine (or any other specific system for that matter), rather it is merely a counter that accumulate flight time of the aircraft in general.
Off this counter an engine accumulated time should be derived.
So the issue of defining a new "0" point for a new countdown remains whether it's for a new engine or not.